# Cannot send email using django and nginx(gunicorn) on digital ocean droplet

Tags: django, email, nginx, gunicorn

I deployed a website using django + nginx + gunicorn on a ubuntu droplet. And I use the email function of django. However, every time I tried to send email, I got a 502 error in my website.

And my nginx error log is:

```
[error] 24933#24933: *30944 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 45.34.23.99, server: server.cn
request: "GET /confirmation-email-send/3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/server.cn.socket:/confirmation-email-send/3/",
host: "server.cn", referrer: "https://server.cn/signup/contestant"
```

Settings.py in django:

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sina.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****@sina.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_FROM = '****h@sina.com'
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/server.cn:

```
server{
charset utf-8;
listen 80;
listen 465;
server_name server.cn;

location /static {
    alias /path/to/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/server.cn.socket;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.cn/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.cn/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

}
```

The function of sending email works well when I run the website at localhost. So I think the problem is in deploying.

I've seen some similar questions but the methods provided can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps... I don't understand why you put listen 465 in your nginx conf
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I think I use `EMAIL_PORT = 465` in settings.py so that port should be listened by nginx...

Comment: No, you put `EMAIL_PORT` to tell Django which port to send the request to on `smtp.sina.com`. AFAIK there is no reason to tell nginx to listen on that port. That said, I haven't gotten this to work yet either.

Comment: @Owen I am facing the same issue. Can you please specify how did you solved this issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did anyone solve this?